# Центроид четырехугольника

Tags: java, математика, вычислительная-геометрия

У меня есть четырехугольник со следующими параметрами:

1. Четырехугольник должен быть выпуклым.
2. Невырожденный выпуклый четырехугольник своими диагоналями делится на четыре невырожденных треугольника.
3. Центроид относится к центру масс простой фигуры, а не к барицентру.
   Другими словами, это должен быть «центр тяжести площади».

Все работает.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для нахождения центроида четырёхугольника можно разложить его на два треугольника, для которых центроиды находятся элементарно, потом найти точку, делящую отрезок между ними пропорционально площадям.

А можно использовать метод, подходящий для любых простых многоугольников.

Найти площадь прямоугольника `Area` - это я уже вам давал [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69231447/formula-for-quadrilateral-area)

Подобным же образом найти величины

```
AX = Sum{i=0..n-1}[(x[i] + x[i+1])*(x[i]*y[i+1]-x[i-1]*y[i])]
AY = Sum{i=0..n-1}[(y[i] + y[i+1])*(x[i]*y[i+1]-x[i-1]*y[i])]
```

и получить координаты центроида

```
CX = AX / (6*Area)
CY = AY / (6*Area)
```

Comment: А в итоге возможно получить не координаты а double?

Comment: Координаты - это два double

Comment: попытаюсь сделать а там посмотрим) если что напишу суда еше, спасибо за помощь

Comment: И я начал понимать в формулах уже))) Ха))

Comment: вот что значит пару ночей читать их....

Comment: Тут просто сумма всех координат Х? (x[i] + x[i+1])

Comment: Нет, сумма двух соседних, умноженная на вторую скобку

Comment: Аха только тех двух...